# Fixed position when parent is relative

Tags: javascript, css

So not sure if this one is possible but from my understanding of the spec the parent of a position fixed element should be the viewport not a parent element with position relative.

That obviously all works when it comes to positioning but not with `z-index`.

If you take a look at this example,

```css
.parent {
  height: 1000px;
}

.el-one {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  color: red;
}

.el-two {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: black;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}

.im-fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="el-one">
    <div class="im-fixed">Hello</div>
  </div>
  <div class="el-two"></div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mmvXaE

The fixed element goes behind the black section if you scroll down, what I need is a way to get the red element to the front without moving it out of el-one.

I have a project where some embed code needs to become fixed when you scroll past it, this is a better example of the actual code. The example above just highlights the issue in a simple way:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="el-one">
    <div id="my-wrapper">
      <iframe class="im-fixed"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="el-two"></div>
</div>
```

,

I found this online talking about what I believe has caused the issue: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/09/Stacking-Changes-Coming-to-position-fixed-elements but no luck finding a workaround.

All I can think of is using JS to move the element from where an editor puts the embed code and prepending it to the body when the user scrolls past the element.

Anyone else come across this or have any ideas?

Comment: because you have same z-index value for both elements?   z-index: 3; in .el-one will fix it

Comment: Just increase the `z-index` of  `.el-one` higher than what you want to overlap

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this? Increase the `z-index` of `.el-one` higher than the one you want to overlap

```css
.parent {
  height: 1000px;
}

.el-one {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  color: red;
}

.el-two {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: black;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}

.im-fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="el-one">
    <div class="im-fixed">Hello</div>
  </div>
  <div class="el-two"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
.el-two {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: black;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I missed an important part out of this question. As I'm creating some embed code that users will post on there sites I only have access to the im-fixed div I can't change any of the rest of the page. This is a bug thats come back from a user that had put the embed code in a page builder

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to solve this issue. Increasing Z-Index, cleaning up the div and etc.

I think you are sort of trying sticky header functionality. There is a new value for position CSS attribute.

`position: sticky`

I have cleaned up the code and removed all Z-Index. Please check the attached code snippet.

Note: Supported only in Chrome, Firefox
Not supported in IE.

```css
.parent {
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5000px;
}

.header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.el-one {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.el-two {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="header">I am a header</div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="el-one">
      I am el-one
    </div>
    <div class="el-two">
      I am el-two
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```